# Click icon in bootstrap text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why can't I click on the icon? If I click it, I don't get an alert.

```js
$('#copy_address').click(function(e) {
  alert("Teszt");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="kapcsolat_email">E-mail cím</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9 inner-addon right-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true" id="copy_address"></i>
    <input class="form-control" id="ajanlatkeres_email" name="ajanlatkeres_email" type="text" value="<?php echo html($data['ajanlatkeres_email']); ?>" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: post your css as well. i tried above code working fine for me.

Comment: run your snippet see it is working. possible issue is in your css of these two classes `inner-addon and right-addon`. post css property of these two classes.

Comment: Css:

.inner-addon {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    
    .inner-addon i {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      pointer-events: none;
      
    }
    
   
    .left-addon in  { left:  0px;}
    .right-addon i { right: 10px; cursor:pointer !important; z-index:999;}
    
    
    .left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
    .right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }

Comment: see my answer below, let me know if it working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `pointer-events: none;`property from css of class `.inner-addon i`. Check the working snippet below

```js
$('#copy_address').click(function(e) {
  alert("Teszt");
});
```

```css
.inner-addon { 
  position: relative; 
} 
.inner-addon i { 
  position: absolute; 
  padding: 10px; 
  /*pointer-events: none;*/ /*remove this property*/ 
} 
.left-addon in { 
  left: 0px;
} 
.right-addon i { 
  right: 10px; 
  cursor:pointer !important; 
  z-index:999;
} 
.left-addon input { padding-left: 30px; } .right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="kapcsolat_email">E-mail cím</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9 inner-addon right-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true" id="copy_address"></i>
    <input class="form-control" id="ajanlatkeres_email" name="ajanlatkeres_email" type="text" value="test@test.com" />
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Now i know, whats the pointer events mean.